# Remove faces in contact with each other

Tags: mesh, optimization

After adding several cubes on top of a plane, the bottom part of those cubes is in contact with the plane. The idea is remove redundant faces that are not seen by the camera to optimized the scene.
In advance thanks, right now is done manually and solving this save me a lot of time.
Cheers

[image]
Ps(I tried with knife intersect, knife boolean, 3d-print)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Intersect Boolean (fast) seems to work, with the benefit of not having to resort to pesky python.

Be sure to first select all of your cubes, then select the plane last.  Enter EDIT mode, 'a' to select all vertices or faces.  Then Face >> Intersect (Boolean).

In the dialog choose the Fast solver instead of Exact.   This seems to give blender the "wiggle room" to find the correct slice.

[image]

I checked the resulting vertices of the cube and then are still at z=0, so that indicates the cubes are still "sealed" onto the plane (e.g., for 3d-print)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python script that would do the trick.  I should probably also check that the object is within the boundaries of the plan.   Let me know if you want a function that does this check as it's hanging around in my scripts somewhere.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

planeName = "myPlane"  # what is the object name of my plane?
plane = bpy.data.objects[planeName]
zLoc = plane.data.vertices.values()[0].co.z
for obj in bpy.context.editable_objects:
    if obj.name == planeName:
        continue
    if obj.type == 'MESH':  # be sure this is a mesh object and not a camera, force, etc
        # create a blender mesh object from the blender object
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
        # look for any face where all 'z' coords touch the same 'z' of the plane
        for face in bm.faces:
            face_aligned=True  # start with assumption all touch
            for vert in face.verts:
                if vert.co.z != zLoc:
                    face_aligned=False  # set to false if not aligned
                    break
            if face_aligned:
                print(obj,face)
                bm.faces.remove(face)  # remove the face from mesh
                bm.to_mesh(obj.data)   # copy the mesh back to the object
                break  # no need to test other faces
```

Comment: Thanks James That's a really nice script. Tomorrow I gonna give it a try. I was thinking kind of the same but rather plane use obj.data.faces for close objects or using a bounding box.